# I am not able to use 'ng-change' in one of my custom AngularJS directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-change, custom-directive

ParentPage.html

```
<records-grid-column ng-change="validateData()" ng-model="name">                     
        {{item.name}}  </records-grid-column>
```

Directive controller

```
   directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: ABCD,
    scope: {
        ngModel:'=',
        ngChange:'&',
        class:'='
    },
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    template: '<td class></td>'
};

return directive;
```

Edit - I changed Modal to model but still i am getting same error ...

Function validateData() is on parent page but on page load i am getting  this error - `'Error: [Error] [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be found!'`

I tried everything but not able to resolve the issue, overall i just to want to call a function to validate the data after its edited and for that i am using 'ngChange'. 
Please let me know where i am wrong, Would be very thankful for help :)

Comment: cf. `modal` and `model`

Comment: I changed but still same error - 'Error: [Error] [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be found!'

Comment: can you give more full code example? Maybe on plunkr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

From

```
  scope: {
        ngModal:'=',
        ngChange:'&',
        class:'='
    }
```

To

```
scope: {
    ngModel:'=',
    ngChange:'&',
    class:'='
}
```

Comment: I changed but still same error - 'Error: [Error] [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be found!'